# Importing hard coded custom field into acf field

Tags: php, custom-field, advanced-custom-fields

I am in the process of migrating posts from an existing wp site into a new wp site. The existing site has a custom field called `subtitle`. When I import the blogs into the new site, I'd like populate my simple [acf](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) `subtitle` text field with these hand coded custom fields.

What is the best way to do this?

Here is the code I've found in the existing sites `single.php` that appears to be creating the sub title field:

`$mt_post_subtitle = get_post_meta($post->ID, "mt_post_subtitle", true);
<?php echo esc_attr($mt_post_subtitle); ?>`

Please let me know if I'm missing something and let me know what I can add to help solve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If I understand it properly, you could try renaming your ACF field from `subtitle` to `mt_post_subtitle` and the `get_post_meta()` should continue to work.

Comment: @Sally CJ that worked. do you want to answer the question officially to take the credit for it? thanks so much.

Comment: Glad it worked! And I've posted an answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you should know that [`get_post_meta()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/) doesn't create any custom fields (or metadata), it only retrieves the custom field's *value*. But the WordPress functions that do create custom fields (for posts) are `add_post_meta()` and `update_post_meta()`.

So that `get_post_meta($post->ID, "mt_post_subtitle", true)` simply retrieves the value of the meta/field named `mt_post_subtitle` for the post (referenced by that `$post`) and as I mentioned in the comment, you could try renaming the ACF field from `subtitle` to `mt_post_subtitle` and the `get_post_meta()` call in your `single.php` (single post) template should continue to work normally.

Alternatively, you could've also used the ACF function for retrieving custom field's value, which is [`get_field()`](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/), but renaming the field name is an easier option in that no code changes needed. :) But for reference, with `get_field()` and without changing the ACF field name, you'd change that `get_post_meta()` to `get_field( 'subtitle', $post->ID )`.